# reinstall all packages with missing in TeX Live

Tags: tlmgr

Let's suppose that `tlmgr check files` shows that some files are missing, because I accidentally removed some files. How do I reinstall all packages with files missing? I have no clue which files are contained by which packages.

I can write a Perl script which reads the `tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb` file, looks for all packages providing files listed by `tmpgr check files` and runs `tlmgr install reinstall ...` on them. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: How do you think files have been removed? If by some update error you should try `tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`.

Comment: My use case is that I ran `rm` to remove some files. (It's not an urgent actual situation though, because currently I know the package names of those files.)